# HQLQueryPlan for Insert

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Hi I am trying to build a Java utility which will churn out all the sqls running in the background of hibernate action.
I started using HQLQueryPlan for the same. It works fine for select, where I have my HqlString built.

But in case of Insert, I have only the object.

Can you help me on how to use HQLQueryPlan to get all the sqls which are getting executed in the background for an Insert OR you can suggest any other API which I may use to suffice my agenda.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the SQL for hibernate by adding the following to your persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
```

It will print out in the server log.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I am aware of this. What I am trying to achieve is to capture these statements in some object for me to use it. I need to get those queries do some operations on them and send it as a Json.